# Share Twitter and Facebook on Android and iPhone with Phonegap 2.0.0

Tags: android, iphone, facebook, cordova, twitter

I have developed an app using Phonegap for Android and IPhone. Is there how to programm the functionality with the Phonegap Framework to share a URL to twitter and Facebook for Android and IPhone?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of hybrid plugins for Phonegap which cover twitter and facebook among other social services:

- [ShareKit for iOs](https://github.com/mohamedfasil/ShareKitPlugin-for-Phonegap-3.0)
- [Share for Android, iOs & WinPhone](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin)

Comment: any option for Windows phone 8

Answer (score 2):

This is really amazing for iOS. Its working with Phonegap Cordova 2.3

https://github.com/bfcam/phonegap-ios-social-plugin

For Android I'm using Android Share Plugin

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Share

Answer (score 1):

The canonical Facebook plugin for Phonegap is here: https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect

It is being updated (by Facebook) to be compatible with the latest iOS and Android SDKs, and so would be recommended...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And i need a link for Twitter. can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following link for twitter on IOS: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/Twitter
For Android: http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt5p1

Answer (score 1):

Currently the best cross-platform social share widget is [this one](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin) which is also [available on PhoneGap Build!](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/382)

It not only supports sharing via the native share widget, but you can also share directly to Facebook, Twitter, Pinterest, etc.